# strange behavior by delete function (mixed C and C++)

Tags: c++, c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm debugging a program where I found some data being changed where they shouldn't. I traced the program using gdb and I found the target data is changed in a `delete` function of some other data!

At first I figured there was some memory overlapping between both areas, but then I checked the start and end addresses of both areas and they do not overlap! that only leaves the `delete` line!

this is the function where this happens, the data that shouldn't change is `freemap` and the data being freed is `synthops`:

```
void BasicBlock::free() {
  cout << "freemap 2 : " << this->mfnlo_loc.chunk->freemap[2] << "\n";
  cout << "freemap 59 : " << this->mfnlo_loc.chunk->freemap[59] << "\n";
  cout << "freemap : " << &(this->mfnlo_loc.chunk->freemap) << "\t" << sizeof(this->mfnlo_loc.chunk->freemap)+&(this->mfnlo_loc.chunk->freemap) << "\n";
  cout << "synthops : " << synthops << "\t" << synthops+sizeof(uopimpl_func_t)*count << "\n";
  if (synthops) 
  {
      delete[] synthops; 
  }
  cout << "freemap 2 : " << (this->mfnlo_loc.chunk->freemap[2]) << "\n";
  cout << "freemap 59 : "  << this->mfnlo_loc.chunk->freemap[59] << "\n";
  synthops = NULL;
  ::free(this);
}
```

the output is like this:

```
freemap 2 : 1
freemap 59 : 1
freemap : 0x3319a50 0x3319a90
synthops : 0x3319d50    0x331acd0
freemap 2 : 0
freemap 59 : 0
```

It is shown that `freemap` changes after the `delete` line, It also shows that they both don't overlap in memory.

`synthops` is allocated in another function like this:

```
bb.synthops = new uopimpl_func_t[bb.count];
```

why does this happen? the code is a mix of C and C++ which means there is a mix of `new` and `malloc` (but used consistently, no `delete` with `malloc` for example). is that the reason for this? or is it something else?

Comment: Does synthops have a destructor?

Comment: All you're showing us is where your program finally breaks down.  In all likelihood, the issue started well before the code you posted is executed.  Also if `BasicBlock` is non-POD, then using `malloc` to create an instance of it is undefined behavior if you use it in any way (other than `placement-new`)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that might be the problem! actually BasicBlock is allocated using malloc. I will change that and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @NeilKirk no, no destructors for that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the problem still persists.

Comment: @ProWi If the class was non-POD, then that is just one hole plugged.  You obviously have more.  But honestly, no one can tell you where the problem actually lies unless we have all the code and run it.  The only thing to tell you is that you are mismanaging pointers and/or the heap somewhere in your application.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually that was the only non-POD allocated with malloc, I was able to overcome the error by taking a copy of freemap before the delete and copying it back after it, It works now but that is not a solution.

Comment: @ProWi No, that isn't a solution.  Might as well put the code back the way it was and really fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you didn't follow the rule of three for `BasicBlock`, specifically you omitted the copy constructor. Then you (shallow) copied that object (and specifically the `synthops` member), and that then resulted in double deletion at which point all bets are off.